# Declare struct inside main()

Tags: c

I am new to C. I got asked to modify this program so that the variables `student` and `anotherStudent` are not global but are local to main.It will still be printed by `printStudnets`. `typedef` is not allowed to use.
I understand if declare struct in main and it would be ascessible to the main function only.Do I have to declare struct in each function to achieve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct student_s {
    char* name;
    int age;
    struct student_s* next;   
} student;
struct student_s anotherStudent;
void printOneStudent(struct student_s student)
{
    printf("%s (%d)\n", student.name, student.age);
}   
void printStudents(const struct student_s* student)
{
    while (student != NULL) {
        printOneStudent(*student);
        student = student->next;
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    student.name = "Agnes McGurkinshaw";
    student.age = 97;
    student.next = &anotherStudent;

    anotherStudent.name = "Jingwu Xiao";
    anotherStudent.age = 21;
    anotherStudent.next = NULL;

    printStudents(&student);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `typedef` in order to define a new structured type. This is perfectly valid:

```
struct student_s {
    char* name;
    int age;
    struct student_s* next;   
}; // Remove "student". Now you don't have a global variable.
```

A consequence of this is that `student_s` is *not* a name of your structured type; it is a *tag* of your structured type. Therefore, declaring objects of structured type corresponding to `student_s` must start with the keyword `struct`:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct student_s student;
    ... // The rest of your code remains the same
}
```